# Как вывести индекс элемента вектора по наличию в нём определённого значения

Tags: c++, vector, find

Вообщем, у меня есть проблема и её очень тяжело описать, но я попробую.

К примеру: есть вектор с двумя строками. Дальше я ищу к примеру букву `o`. Если он есть в `1-ой` строке вектора, то выводится индекс строки, т.е. `0`, но если буквы `о` нет в `1-ой` строке, а есть во `2-ой`, то следовательно выводим `1`, а если вообще нигде нет буквы `о`, то выводим `-1`.

Думаю немного, но суть передал.

```
vector<string> lorem = {"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry.", "Xorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy"};


// псевдокод
auto a = lorem.find('o'); // a = 0, т.к. в 1-ой строке есть "о"

auto b = lorem.find('X'); // b = 1, т.к. во 2-ой строке есть "X"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл по всем элементам с `std::string::find()`. Нашли - выходим, не нашли продолжаем.

Псевдокод:

```
bool found = false;
size_t index = 0;

while (!found) {
    str = strings[index++];
    found = str.find_first_of(symbol) != npos;
}
```

Comment: Можете накинуть набросок? Там уже пойму как доделать под свою нужду.

Comment: @lakvak `strings` - вектор строк,  вызываем у строк `find_first_of`, например. Считаем индекс обычной переменной, если надо

Comment: А что значит `str.find_first_of(symbol) != npos;`?

Comment: @lakvak ну почитайте документацию https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of. Функция-член возвращает индекс первого совпадения или npos, если его не было. Проверяем, npos там или нет, и выставляем флаг

Comment: Всё равно так и не дошло что за `npos`, но всё-равно спасибо!

Comment: @lakvak считайте, что `npos = (std::size_t) -1`

Comment: Наконец-то дошло!! извиняюсь за тупость

Comment: @lakvak вот пример ещё https://stackoverflow.com/q/3827926

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
std::find_if(lorem.cbegin(), lorem.cend(),
             [](auto const &s){ return s.find('o') != s.npos; });
```